# Page Scroll gets very slow after ajax server request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using jQuery ajax to verify some records from the database. The page scroll gets very slow after the user performs ajax request.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({  
            url:"myUrl",
            type:"POST",
            data:myData,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(response){
                var obj = eval(response);
                if(obj.error == 1){  
                    console.log('record exits');
                }       
            }


        });
```

Comment: Don't ever use `eval`! BTW, what's in `response`?

Comment: Response is working absolutely fine, just the page scroll gets very slow...